# RhodeCode commit dont work with tortoisehg

Tags: mercurial, commit, tortoisehg, rhodecode

I use RhodeCode for a web-based frontend for mercurial. Clone work with successful auth, but all commits with tortoisehg end in /dev/null, like they never have existed. No error shown in tortoisehg, even in any log file. Commiting dirctly with the webinterface is working ....

Comment: By "commit", do you mean "push"? If not, that's your problem.

Comment: -.- -> I need more sleep. Thx

Answer (score 0):

Please check your rhodecode log for any messages when doing Push via Tortoise maybe it fails on authentication ? From our side there are no compatibilty issues with TurtoiseHG.